# cakephp join query is not working

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am new in cake php.I want to write join query between two table.Here my query is :

```
select * from deal_purchases as dp 
  join users as u on u.id = dp.user_id
  where dp.deal_id = 6
  group by user_id
```

and this query run perfect.But I want to write this query in cakephp. I have written this query like :

```
$table = "deal_purchases";
$query['conditions'] = array('deal_purchases.deal_id'=>$deal_id);
$query['fields'] = array('deal_purchases.*','users.*');
$query['joins'] = array(
                    array(
                        'table'=>'users',
                        'alias'=>'users',
                        'type'=>'INNER',
                        'conditions'=>array('users.id = deal_purchases.user_id')
                        ),
                );
$query['group'] = array('deal_purchases.user_id');
$result = $this->find('all', $query);
```

Here this query is not execute so how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: May I know which cakephp version using and where you want the query(ex controller name or model name)

Comment: @MathsRkBala I  have used CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9 version. And I have written query in controller.

Comment: May I know your controller name(DealPurchasesController or any othername)

Comment: @MathsRkBala controller name is **MerchantController**.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the following your file:

Your controller top "`$uses`" array contain "`DealPurchase`"
Example

```
class MerchantController extends AppController {
    var $uses = array(
        'DealPurchase'
    );
```

Try the following

```
$query['conditions'] = array('DealPurchase.deal_id'=>$deal_id);
$query['fields'] = array('DealPurchase.*','User.*');
$query['joins'] = array(
                    array(
                        'table'=>'users',
                        'alias'=>'User',
                        'type'=>'INNER',
                        'conditions'=>array('User.id = DealPurchase.user_id')
                        ),
                );
$query['group'] = array('DealPurchase.user_id');
$result = $this->DealPurchase->find('all', $query);
```

**database table deal_purchases** For Model Name should be `DealPurchase.php` in the following format

```
<?php 
class DealPurchase extends AppModel {
    var $name = "DealPurchase";
    //Relationship some tables
    //Validation here
}
?>
```

**User.php Model(users)**

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = "User"; 
    var $hasMany = array(
        'DealPurchase' => array(
            'className' => 'DealPurchase',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => true //true means when delete the user entry via coding then also deleted the deal_purchases entry also
        )
    );
    //validation
}
```

**DealPurchase.php Model(deal_purchases)**

```
class DealPurchase extends AppModel {
    var $name = "DealPurchase"; 
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );
    //validation
}
```

Comment: What is the meanig of var $uses = array(
        'DealPurchase'
    );

Comment: Include the model(DealPurchase) in your controller, you can access the data in (deal_purchases table) any where in your(Merchant Controller). The deal_purchases model name should be DealPurchase.php

Comment: How to write relationship of table in model file?

Comment: I added example please refer it

Comment: I have follow all steps that you have said but its not working.

Comment: @Nisarg if you use relationship means you will try the following query $result = $this->DealPurchase->find('all',array(
   'conditions' => array('DealPurchase.deal_id'=>$deal_id), 
   'fields' => array(
    'DealPurchase.*'
   ),
   'recursive' => 1    
  )); In case any error please comment the error message